# Android onOptionsItemSelected avoid double click

Tags: android, android-menu

How to avoid double click on my example, any solutions?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.testing) {
                Dialog();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more?

Comment: On my ActionBar i click many time, and have many time AlertDialog

Comment: You need only one time right? You don't want the second click? Am i understand right?

Comment: yes, I need only one click

Comment: every time call dialog.dismiss() before you show dialog.show();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is many way to achieve this. I am telling only sample example.

Just create a boolean variable in Activity class.

```
Boolean isClicked = false;
```

and then

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.testing) {
    if (!isClicked){
//Change here as your flag is true
isClicked = true;
                    Dialog();
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Then this dialog shows only one time. If any changes needed ask.

Comment: where you changed on true value?

Comment: how about for grouped menu items? does the isClicked will conflicted each others? @amsheer

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, but nothing from below options worked for me..

1. Disabling view clicability - appeared to be too slow for "MAD
   CLICKER"
2. setting some boolean (like isClicked to true) on click and checking it in onClickListener - looks fast, but not enough

Finally got a method which prevents "mad double click behaviour" on Menu items, which is even worse than double click on simple button, imo.

// define Fragment / Activity variable

```
volatile private byte saveClickCounter = 0;
```

// implement

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {            
        case R.id.common_action_save:

            if (saveClickCounter++ == 0) {
                saveButtonClick();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "OMG! U R fast!");
            }

            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Don't forget to make that variable equal to zero again (or decrease that), after successfull method call.

`saveClickCounter--;`

Answer (score 1):

Another easy approach is similar with @AlexV, use increment operator

Create a global variable

```
private var saveClickCounter: Int = 0
```

In onOptionsItemSelected

```
val id = item.itemId
    if (id == R.id.save)
    {
        if (saveClickCounter == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "clickedd")
            saveClickCounter++
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OMG! U R fast!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem here is that MAD CLICKER can click twice before your counter is set to ++ . So you have to put your increment as next after evaluation, or do it atomic once. Even if code in brackets looks very simple and lightweight.